# In MongoDb Morphia how to delete or replace an array object

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I can only find how to remove first, last or selected object
but i need to delete the entire array.

In Morphia i have this below `Document` `FriendList`.

In the `Document` you see the `array` `friendList`.
I need to update this `array` with new `"friends"`.

What need to happen is i must delete all entries in the `friendList`
before populating it with new friends.

Was thinking i could delete it and then simply insert a new
`array`  `friendList` containing `"friends"`.

How can i delete the `array`?

Maybe im all wrong about how to do this since i cannot find a solution..

```
@Entity
public class FriendList {

    @Id private ObjectId id;

    public Date lastAccessedDate;

    @Indexed(name="uuid", unique=true,dropDups=true)  
    private String uuid;


    List<String> friendList;

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public List<String> getFriendList() {
        return friendList;
    }

    public void insertFriend(String friend) {
        this.friendList.add(friend);
    }

}
```

from the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating) I try this in various combinations with no luck:

```
mongo.createUpdateOperations(FriendList.class).removeAll("friendList", "??");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the unset method, and then addAll or just use set:

http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating#set/unset

Should look something like this:

```
ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(FriendList.class).unset("friendList");
datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(FriendList.class).addAll("friendList", listOfFriends);
datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
```

or with set:

```
ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(FriendList.class).set("friendList", listOfFriends);
datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
```

Answer (score -2):

In general you'd only need to use general (Java) list operations - so to clear it, set the list to null, remove or add entries as you require,... So you can simply load, manipulate, and then persist the entity very easily.

Why do you even have `mongo.createUpdateOperations(FriendList.class)`? If an object is pretty big, you might not want to load and persist the entire thing for updating a single field. However, I would start with the simple approach and only use more complicated queries if required.

Don't optimize prematurely - build, benchmark, and optimize as required!

EDIT:

In your entity:

```
public function clearFriends(){
    this.friendList = null;
}
```

Wherever you need it:

```
FriendList friendList = ...
friendList.clearFriends();
persistence.persist(friendList); // Assuming you have some kind of persistence service with a persist() method
```

Or you can use some special Morphia methods, like unset, but this might be an overkill...

Comment: Im a bit new to this. How using Morphia should i set the list to null? What other can i use if createUpdateOperations is unsuitable. or if you can tell me where in the docmentation this is described.

Comment: just figure it out i think using the "unset" command on the property.

Comment: I've added a short example above (comments are no good for code...)

Comment: Yes, you can just save it again as well; the update method will send less data to the server and reduces the chance that other changes (set via updates) collide on the server which could more than just an optimization...

Comment: (in case you are not updating - just to avoid confusions)

Comment: Yes, @Version can be used to keep any collision from happening, but it means that all updates to the same entity would have to be serialized and you would get an error if you tried to save an already updated entity. This may be exactly what you want, depending on your application requirements.